# Facebook Marketing insights Grouped By Day

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How is possible to get insights grouped by days?
Means get one row per day with all the statistics.
I see that I can use "hourly_stats_aggregated_by_audience_time_zone" in "breakdowns" but I dont know exactly what is the result.
I need one record each day depending from the level (for instance is I choose level=campaign) I need to have campaign_id, campaign_name, day, spent
Is is possible?
Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter that I'm looking for is "time_increment" equals 1.
Here is the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.5

Answer (score 0):

Usually, facebook insight URLs are compiled like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<object>/insights/<metric>/<period>
```

in your example something like

```
175527252532294/insights/page_impressions/day?breakdowns=/hourly_stats_aggregated_by_audience_time_zone
```

where `<object>` is your page/ad/post/app/... ID

You may try it first over here: [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=OBJECTID%2Finsights%2Fpage_impressions%2Fday%3Fbreakdowns[0]%3D%2Fhourly_stats_aggregated_by_audience_time_zone&version=v2.5)

Comment: Thanks Alex I will try it.
Where I can find the docs of this syntax? I don't found anything in FB API docs

Comment: Graphh Explorer is your source. There's no "syntax description" of the URL as in other APIs, so you must invest some R&D efforts